# Can the Windows calculator history be displayed on a new window?

Tags: windows, calculator

I want to use the Windows calculator and display the History on a new window. The main goal is to use two displays, one which is touchscreen and will be used to interact with the calculator, and the second display which will show the result (history) of the calculation.

As far as I can see, the history is integrated into the calculator within the same window, and cannot be separated.

Please let me know if this is at all possible, or knowledge of an application that can do this.

Comment: It cannot be separated.

Comment: Do you know of any applications that could provide this? Or perhaps modifying the code to display the result on a new frame? It is open source

Comment: There are **many**: https://alternativeto.net/software/windows-calculator but this site does not offer software recommendations. See https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Ramhound, how did you determine that?  It seems to be at https://github.com/microsoft/calculator.

Comment: That is what I thought as well @LarryEngholm but I am not familiar with C# enough to come up with the solution I need